# Teams applications: Auto-suggestions actions are automatically opened in our chat

Tags: botframework, bots, chat, microsoft-teams

When we open the Teams applications with a chat the auto-suggestions menu is automatically opened.
Are there any way to disable it?
We tried it for few different MS Teams apps and it is reproduced for all.
It is reproduced in ~90% cases.
We started facing it recently and didn't remember such behaviour before.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open app with chat

Expected result:
Auto-suggestion menu is not opened

Actual result:
Auto-suggestion menu is opened

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be expected behaviour of Bot having commands. These bot commands will pop up automatically. There is no way to disable it